# Angular 4 Production build reflect no changes

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am working in angular 4. When i make changes into local its working fine but when i build my application using ng build --prod it reflect no changes on production website dist is same as it were before. angular cli version is

```
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.4.4
node: 8.11.4
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.4
@angular/common: 4.4.4
@angular/compiler: 4.4.4
@angular/core: 4.4.4
@angular/forms: 4.4.4
@angular/http: 4.4.4
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.4
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.4
@angular/router: 4.4.4
@angular/cli: 1.4.4
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.4
@angular/language-service: 4.4.4
typescript: 2.3.4
```

Comment: if u run `ng serve --prod` do the changes get applied?

Answer (score 0):

Are the files in the dist such as bundles have a hash preceeding the name? ex. Vendor.bundles.eqwkeu23894u3d.js ??

IIf So, it's working, also have you compared the bundle sizes from not doing --prod and then doing --prod. ng build --prod should build for production.

try `ng build --env=prod --target=prod`

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Comment: Invalid build target. Only 'development' and 'production' are available. getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying what's in the dist folder does not get updated? Low chance that this is it, but maybe check angular-cli.json and see if you have this line: `"outDir": "dist"`.

Comment: Yeap i have this line angular-cli.json

Answer (score 0):

Please try deleting the dist folder then run `ng build --prod --verbose` so you can get the proper output and paste that here. Also is this just a starter project or does it actually have code? And lastly can you confirm if the build command doesn't error out ?